# Bash shell - Extract dirname from a file folder saved in a string

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I can't use the "dirname" command because this is a string and not a really directory.
So, I extract my dirname and filename only using regexp.

Example:

```
filefolder=/home/ubuntu/Desktop/photo.jpg
```

If I want to extract the filename, I use: `filename=${filefolder##*/}`. It works, and returns as result: "photo.jpg".

If I want to extract the dirname, what kind of regexp can I use?
I've tried with NOT operator before "`*/`" in this way: `dirname=${filefolder##^[*/]}` but doesn't work.

Any idea to solve it?

Comment: `$(dirname /home/ubuntu/Desktop/photo.jpg)` works on my system (the directory does not exist).

Comment: how about save file folder in a txt file, and then grep it as so:  grep -o '\.*\' file

Answer (score 2):

The *opposite* of the `${..##..}` is `${..%%..}`:

```
~$ filefolder=/home/ubuntu/Desktop/photo.jpg
~$ filedir=${filefolder%/*}
~$ echo $filedir
/home/ubuntu/Desktop
```

It's one of the [parameter substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PCTPATREF):

> ${var%Pattern}, ${var%%Pattern}
>
> ${var%Pattern} Remove from $var the shortest part of $Pattern that matches the back end of $var.
>
> ${var%%Pattern} Remove from $var the longest part of $Pattern that matches the back end of $var.

An alternative is to use the `dirname`/`basename` commands:

```
~$ dirname $filefolder
/home/ubuntu/Desktop
~$ basename $filefolder
photo.jpg
```